# image not get delete from folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

**my .cs code**

```
   int ID = 24; 
   DAL objdal = new DAL();  //class
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt = objdal.select_delete_image(ID);  //method to select and delete
   string imagedel = "";
  if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     //image delete
     imagedel = dt.Rows[0]["image_url"].ToString();
     File.Delete((Server.MapPath("~/Admin/images/projects/small/" + imagedel.ToString())));       // process to delete
     File.Delete((Server.MapPath("~/Admin/images/projects/large/" + imagedel.ToString())));        // process to delete             

  }
     string strScript = "<script language='JavaScript'>alert('Image Deleted Successfully')</script>";
     Page.RegisterStartupScript("PopUp", strScript);
```

here the database entry is deleted, but the image from the folder is not deleted.

This all works fine in localhost but problem occurs on server side

Comment: Try using `File.Exists(....)` if returns true, than it should delete the file if you have file access permission.

Comment: show me the image
 urls which saved in database...

Comment: could you please check whether your "File.Delete" is actually get executed. File.Delete should throw an error if it not able to delete the file, or are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0):

If this code deleted data from Database dt = objdal.select_delete_image(ID); then how  this statement works (dt.Rows.Count > 0), Cross Check whether dt contains any data or not. IF it having data, then cross your file path you are providing to delete image. May be your File Path is not correct well.

Comment: i have checked my dt, it brings image names from my database, and image path is also correct.

Comment: Try this , Check whether your file exists or not if (TheFile1.Exists)
                {
                    File.Delete(MapPath("Foldername") + "\\"  + "imagedel");

                }

Comment: the image file is already there, i can see the file in FTP(filezila). and if i manually delete the image from FTP, then it will give the error "550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."